# Issue in HTML5 facebook Like box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I using Facebook Like box in our site. but when people who liked so the facebook display there user thumb images it hide.

where i am doing wrong??? 
how to fix? please let me know.

See below link Facebook code & display. please click on like button after check it.

See Live demo: www.jsfiddle.net/aQnjC/

See screenshot [Click Here](http://demo.harnishdesign.net/like.jpg).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is happening that is a problem? or what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: it is working fine before like. but issue is when any user like so after not display proper like box. See screenshote [link](http://demo.harnishdesign.net/like.jpg)